# How does a < b < c and a + b + c = s imply a < s/3 and b < s/2?

Tags: inequality, project-euler

I've been trying to understand the overview given for [problem 9 on Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9) and it mentions that the upper bound for iterating through possible values of a is (s - 3)/3 and for b it is (s - a)/2. I don't understand how they got these values. In googling for possible explanations, I found several places where they use s/3 as an upper bound for a and s/2 for b.

Now, s/3 for a I understand because a + b + c = s and since a < b < c. How do you get the others?

Comment: This result holds if $0<a$. Otherwise, consider $-2<2<3$: $-2+2+3=3$ and $2>3/2$. You get the second estimate by passing to $b+c<s$ and using $b<c$.

Comment: Right you are. Forgot to mention that a, b and c were natural numbers. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a, b, c$ are *integers,* so that $a < b < c$ implies $b \ge a +1 $ and $ c \ge b+1  \ge a+2$. Therefore
$$
 s = a+b+c \ge a + (a+1) + (a+2) = 3a+3
$$
gives the first estimate. Similarly,
$$
 s -a = b+c \ge b + (b+1) = 2b +1
$$
gives the second estimate.